# IIS Application Pool and Sql Server Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, iis, windows-authentication, application-pool

I have an app running within IIS, inside an Application pool running under a User with SQL Server access.

Windows authentication doesn't seem to be picking up the User's account though.

---

Any ideas on how I can proceed with this? It's really confusing

Comment: so is the question!   not enough info...

Comment: this sounds like a question for serverfault, so I've voted to send it that way. If you can add more info that makes it clearer that it's a programming question, I'll give it a shot though, as I've some experience doing battle with iis & sql server =)

Comment: Hi sorry for not enough info, was afraid that if I went in more detail I would get no replies. I've just started with iis and sql server... i'm loosing my battle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have unmarked anonymous user on IIS otherwise it won't pick up the user name

Comment: AuthenticationMethod Tab. have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPDOTNETauthentication.aspx

Comment: awesome link thanks so much! Can you put this in the answer so I can tick it? :)

Comment: You can click on the link even if it's a comment :-)